# What does clean mean in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is an obvious question for everyone, but I don't understand what the term "clean" means. I can use clean_data, and use form validation on my forms. However, I still don't understand what this means.

In order to use validation, do I always need to use the keyword "clean"?

Comment: are you talking about `clean_<fieldname>() `? or `clean()`?

Comment: The word itself "clean" in django, what is it referring to? Why do they call it clean?

Comment: Because it's cleaning the data and validating it. If you have a primary key field on your form and you send it the ID of a model in your database, it will "clean" it up and convert it into the model instance.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying "it's cleaning the data". What does that mean? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe this section will clarify things for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning

Comment: I read that. I guess I'm taking the world too literally. I will continue to look at it until the lightbulb turns on. Thank you

Comment: are you asking what cleaning data means? as what are we "cleaning"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation)

> The clean() method on a Field subclass is responsible for running
>   to_python(), validate(), and run_validators() in the correct order and
>   propagating their errors. If, at any time, any of the methods raise
>   ValidationError, the validation stops and that error is raised. This
>   method returns the clean data, which is then inserted into the
>   cleaned_data dictionary of the form.

Clean is preventing dirty data in DB

Comment: I would advice to add an example to the answer: let's say you have a Product model which has 'name' field and it needs to be unique, in a form you would need to clean that field to be all lowercase and remove trailing whitespaces so when a user inputs a 'name' all lowercase and a 'name' with first uppercase both inputs are treated the same and the form can properly raise an exception (both names are the same) so the former cannot be accepted as valid input (you need to input a different name for the product.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i have understood ..all the implicit validations are performed using clean..
which is performed when we check for the form validity using is_valid:

but we can add our own validations to it by overriding the function clean():
what we have to do is we call the super().clean() such that all the implicit validations are done by the clean() defined by django and then add our own validations to it if necessary...

when you call the super().clean() it returns the dictionary containing the cleaned_data..
you can store it in a variable ...
or else you can access the dictionary using self.cleaned_data